# Is it possible a variable get the result of return?

Tags: javascript

**Here is my code;**

```
var notificar = prompt("qual é seu nome ?");

function teste(name) {
    // return name +" Voce é o aluno";
    var teste =  return false;
}

if ( teste == false) {
    alert("Olá amiguinhos da tv (teste == false)");
} else {
    alert(" Ola amiguinhas da tv ??? (teste == true)");
}

alert(teste(notificar));
```

*I'd like to retrieve a boolean of return so that I can do my condition structure*

Comment: what should be tested inside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with global var like the way you want to do this.
And the structure must be corrent example;

```js
var notificar = prompt("qual é seu nome ?");

// Declare global variable here
var teste;

function teste(name) {
    // return name +" Voce é o aluno";
    // Set the global variable to (in this ase) false
    teste = false;
}

// First run the function to set the boolean
teste(notificar)

// Than do the check what teste is

if (teste == false) {
    alert("Olá amiguinhos da tv ");
} else {
    alert(" Ola amiguinhas da tv ???");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line `var teste =  return false;`

It will give `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return` error.

And even if you change it to `return false;` the below code will not execute because you return form the execution.

So, I think the only solution is just assign `false` to `var teste`

i.e. `var teste =  false;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you try to execute your code, you'll get a syntax error. As you want to retrieve the value that your function returns you can execute it and atribute the variable, just like that:

```
var notificar = prompt("qual é seu nome ?");

function fnTeste(name) {
     return false;
}

var teste = fnTeste(notificar); // Here is the attribuition

if ( teste == false) {
    alert("Olá amiguinhos da tv ");
} else {
    alert(" Ola amiguinhas da tv ???");
}

alert(fnTeste(notificar));
```

Notice that the variable "teste" is using the value of the function "fnTeste" as you want (they can't have the same name, as they are used for diferent purposes).

I hope it helps!